# Cypress Sum of two array

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress

[image]

hi all, i want to sum of two columns values in a cypress .

i declared  two array variable : quantity and price , and push all columns elements as well.
 if i log the quantity cy.log(quantity) it shows all values in array. but `cy.log(quantity[1])` is not working. same in price array.

i don't know why it's not behave like a array.

if i declare , a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] and then `cy.log(a[1])` , it's working

i have to sum both of the arrays. tried many approaches.

```
var quantity =[]
var price =[]

cy.get('td:nth-child(10) > div > span:visible').each(($el, index, $list) => 
        {
            quantity.push(Number($el.text())).toFixed(4)

        })

        cy.get('td:nth-child(14) > div > span:visible').each(($el, index, $list) => 
        {  
            price.push(Number($el.text())).toFixed(4)
        })

     cy.log(quantity) // working
     cy.log(price) // working

     cy.log(quantity[1]) //not working
     cy.log(price[3])  //not working

     // this part is working:
        var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
        cy.log(a[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set both the array values within the same `then`:

```
cy.get('tr').then(($trs) => {
    const price = [];
    const quantity = [];
    $trs.each((idx, $el) => {
        const value1 = Number(cy.$$($el).find(':nth-child(10)> div > span:visible').text());
        price.push(Number(value1.toFixed(4)));

        const value2 = Number(cy.$$($el).find(':nth-child(10)> div > span:visible').text());
        quantity.push(Number(value2.toFixed(4)));
    });

    const sum = price.map((p, index) => (p + quantity[index]).toFixed(2));
    cy.log('Price: ' + price);
    cy.log('Quantity: ' + quantity);
    cy.log('price[1]: ' + price[1]);
    cy.log('quantity[1]: ' + quantity[1]);
    cy.log('Sum = ' + sum);
});
```

Screenshot from my test:

[image]

Corresponding `Markup`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5.42342</td>
    <td>2.442</td>
    <td>6.767678</td>
    <td>6767.678</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7.6343543</td>
    <td>8.44</td>
    <td>84.554</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Number($el.eq(9).find('> div > span:visible').text())
this will give me only one value.  how to get all values from the row?

Comment: i don't know why Quantity is not behaving like a array. 
cy.log(quantity[1]) this  is not working

Comment: Please check the modified answer.

Comment: please check my questions:

Comment: Please check the modified answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. i used to sum of two arrays using below. its working.

```
model=[]
  lower=[]
    var squares = model.map((a, i) => a.toFixed(4) - lower[i].toFixed(4));
```

but my result is like:

`[0.01, 0.019999999999999997, 0.060000000000000005, 0.04, 0.09000000000000001, 0.019999999999999997, 0.08, 0.35, 0.12000000000000001, 0.07, 0.03]`.

how to fixed with two decimal points